# Nest JS role and permission based access control

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs, rbac, casl

I've already worked with nodeJS and express. Now I came across NestJS and found it quite interesting.

There are several references to authorization in the NestJS documentation.

- RBAC (role-based access control)
- CASL (claims-based authorization)

But I'm not sure which of the many variants meet my requirements.

The aim is to create a REST API where on the one hand server-side permissions (rights to call up the route or change data records) and client-side permissions (which widgets are displayed in the frontend, what can the user see ) covers.

I programmed everything myself in NodeJS and express, but in NestJS it is certainly easier to solve than to reinvent the wheel.

The question arises with which packages i covered everything.

**example for server side permissions**

```
PUT api-domain / api / v1 / users /: id
```

It should be ensured that the user has the permission to call the route and of course it should also be ensured that, for example, a normal user can only edit his own user, but an admin in turn can edit everything.

**example for client side permissions**

payload from JWT token

```
userID: 15af1as85f1as81f8as1f
client-permissions: [“DASHBOARD”, “USER_MENUE_WIDGET”, “NAVIGATION_TOP_WIDGET”]
```

The payload of the JWT token contains an array with the required client permissions which the user is presented with.

I hope this is understandable am open to any kind of suggestions :)

Many thanks in advance,
Alessandro

Comment: _The payload of the JWT token contains an array with the required client permissions which the user is presented with._ I would not recommend this, because if permissions are changed, your client would still be working with older permissions till the token is refreshed.

Comment: Use guards, you could have an authentication guard to verify the token which would also add the client permissions to the request object. Use another guard to check for permissions by reading the updated request from the previous guard.
When using `@UseGuards()` call the auth guard before the other